# PHP and CRON based MySQL database dump-to-email backup system?

Tags: mysql, database, email, cron, backup

Can anyone recommend a reliable and simple PHP based MySQL database backup system that can run on the same virtualhost, creates a dump file from a specific database and sends it as an attachment to an e-mail address with frequency I can adjust (or depending on CRON).

Thanks!

Comment: do you want he script or have u tried something

Comment: I'm looking for some backup software or script I could install, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you can set up a CRON job with this command:

```
mysqldump db_name > path_to_file.text
```

replace the placeholders with your database name and the path to the file you want to dump to.  As for the e-mail part. I'm not sure.

Comment: It runs on a virtualhost, I'm not sure I am able to do that. I'd just run a script with CRON and have it do what I need. I'm looking for some backup software or script I could install, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: "I'm not sure I am able to do that".  What is it you're not sure you're able to do? Run a MySQL command?  Is your MySQL database on the same virtual host as your site?  If so, then running that code in CRON should work.  Or are you trying NOT to use CRON?

Comment: I do not want to reinvent the wheel. I need a script or solution that, when queried, creates a dump of one or more databses, attaches them to an e-mail and sends them to a specific e-mail address, potentially addresses various problems that might occur. I do not want to reinvent the wheel, I'm sure there is something like that already there.